# Preloading image gracefully in Javascript (without any JS library)?

Tags: javascript, image, src, preloading

I have an image with set src attribute.

I would like to replace image, but connection with the server is slow and time that it takes to load a new image is not negligible.

Is there possibility to create internal Image object, set kind of "onLoadListener" on it, load an image and then set it to original image src attribute?

Comment: It is possible, but it depends on the caching settings of the client. If caching is turned off completely by the client, you'll have a doubled request count. (one for the attempt to preload an image, one for the actual display) (using `Image`)

Comment: Fortunately caching is enabled in my use case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-load images in JavaScript like this...

```
myImage = new Image();
myImage.onload = function () { alert("Loaded"); };
myImage.src = "logo.gif";
```

You can put the logic to pop the image on the page instead of alert-ing.

Comment: But when my connection is slow user will see empty Image for a while. So I should load Image like this and set myActualImageOnPage.src = myImage.src

Comment: @pixel yes, he means to change the `src` on your real element during the `onload` method of your dummy image object.